# Dependency Injection and AutoMapper in ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, automapper

I´ve started coding recently and was given a project where I have little experience. I´m building a Web Api in ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework 4.7.2) and need to use dependency injection and AutoMapper. To resolve these I have used Ninject that seems to work fine however, I need to Map a source object to an internal Dto and the source object reference is in the DLLs. In my project I only have the class for the Dto. When I add the assemblies I must change the property Copy Local to false so won´t have the DLLs in the bin folder. Instead I would like to look for the assembly using the Environment Variable. How can I config the NinjectResolver so it will look for the assemblies through environment variable and then execute the objects mapping?
Many thanks in advance.

Here is my code for Ninject:

```
public class NinjectResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectResolver() : this(new StandardKernel())
    {
    }

    public NinjectResolver(IKernel ninjectKernel, bool scope = false)
    {
        kernel = ninjectKernel;
        if (!scope)
        {
            AddBindings(kernel);
        }
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new NinjectResolver(AddRequestBindings(new ChildKernel(kernel)), true);
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    private void AddBindings(IKernel kernel)
    {
        // singleton and transient bindings go here
    }

    private IKernel AddRequestBindings(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IClienteRepository>().To<ClienteRepository>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<IArtigoRepository>().To<ArtigoRepository>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<IArtigoMoedaRepo>().To<ArtigoMoedaRepo>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<IDocCompraRepo>().To<DocCompraRepo>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<IDocVendaRepo>().To<DocVendaRepo>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<ILinhasDocCompraRepo>().To<LinhasDocCompraRepo>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<ILinhasDocVendaRepo>().To<LinhasDocVendaRepo>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<IMapper>().ToMethod(context =>
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
                cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t => kernel.Get(t));// tell automapper to use ninject when creating value converters and resolvers
            });
            return config.CreateMapper();
        }).InSingletonScope();

        return kernel;
    }
}
```

Code for WebApiConfig:

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        

        config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

The code for the mappings:

```
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<BasBECliente, ClienteDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<BasBEArtigoMoeda, ArtigoMoedaDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<BasBEArtigo, ArtigoDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<BasBEArtigo, ArtigoInsertDto>().ReverseMap();  //.ForMember(x => x.ArtigoMoeda, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<CmpBEDocumentoCompra, DocCompraDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<VndBEDocumentoVenda, DocVendaDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<VndBELinhaDocumentoVenda, LinhaDocVendaDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CmpBELinhaDocumentoCompra, LinhaDocCompraDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Finally, what i usually do to find the DLLs through the environment variable:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

    static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        string assemblyFullName;

        System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyName;

        assemblyName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name);
        assemblyFullName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PERCURSOSGP100", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine), assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(assemblyFullName))
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullName);
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: So the provided code does not work now? What error/problem does it give you?

Comment: It works however needs adjustments. With AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);  It searches for the assemblies using the environment variable but for the objects mapping (code in NinjectResolver class) gets them from the bin folder. Considering the fact that the cliente could have different DLL versions, I must not set the DLL attribute Copy to Local to true, instead I should have some configurations in Ninject to actually look for the envirnment variable. And here comes the problem, I cannot find a way of config this.

Comment: I placed the ' AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);' before config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(); in the WebApiConfig class Register method, but i should actually have a similar configuration in the NinjectResolver for the Imapper bind

Comment: "code in NinjectResolver class) gets them from the bin folder" - are you sure, how did you check that? `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` should be app domain wide setting so if you set it from the start fo you app it should work the same way for all the code.

Comment: The issue comes in the MapperConfiguration. I get an error here: 'cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();' as the first object (BasBECliente) is not a class in my project but an object from a DLL. When it tries to map from BasBECliente to ClienteDto - 'CreateMap<BasBECliente, ClienteDto>().ReverseMap();' - if the DLL is not in the bin folder It throws an exception saying it cannot load the assembly. IIn case the DLLs are in bin is able to execute the mapping however, as mentioned, is not good practise having the DLLs in the bin as the cliente might have different versions of those.

Comment: Try defining preprocessor directive `NO_APPDOMAIN_ISOLATION` for build. (more info about directives [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#defining-symbols) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#defineconstants))